# Exception Using Sockets in Android Studio

Tags: android, sockets, exception, android-studio, android-asynctask

I am just starting my first Android Application and have a problem using sockets in Android Studio.

I'm trying to esablish a connection to a server. I'm doing this using Async Tasks. When I start the app, the socket get's created and sending the first package is working fine. But when I try to send another package, it throws an exception saying the socket is closed.

I tried many things, such as checking, if the socket is connected before sending the second package and if not, creating a new one. Debugging in Android Studio shows me, the Socket "nsocket" is never closed. here is a screenshot of me debugging the code: [Debugging-Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi7yQ.png)

Here is my Async Task Code:

```
public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Boolean> {
    private boolean finished = false;
    private boolean socket = false;
    private boolean messageSuccess = false;
    Socket nsocket; //Network Socket
    InputStream nis; //Network Input Stream
    OutputStream nos; //Network Output Stream
    SocketAddress sockaddr;

    Client c = new Client();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) { //This runs on a different thread
        socket = false;
        try {
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Creating socket");
            sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(SERVERHOST, SERVERPORT);
            nsocket = new Socket();
            nsocket.connect(sockaddr, 10000); //10 second connection timeout
            socket = true;
            while (finished) {
                finished = false;
                if (nsocket.isConnected()) {
                    Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Socket created, streams assigned");
                    Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Waiting for inital data...");
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: IOException");
            socket = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Exception");
            socket = false;
        }
        return socket;
    }
    public boolean closeSocket() {
        try {
            //nis.close();
            nos.close();
            nsocket.close();
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "closeSocket: Finished");
            socket = false;
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "closeSocket: IO Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "closeSocket: Socket or output Stream already closed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            socket = false;
            return false;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "closeSocket: Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

    public boolean SendDataToNetwork(final String cmd) { //You run this from the main thread.

        if (!nsocket.isClosed()) {
            Log.i("AsyncTask", getString(R.string.StatusSendAlarm));
            Log.i("AsyncTask", cmd);
            messageSuccess = false;
            publishProgress("1".getBytes());
            try {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            nos = nsocket.getOutputStream();
                            nos.write(cmd.getBytes());
                            nos.flush();
                            nos.close();

                            finished = true;
                            messageSuccess = true;
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.i(TAG, "SendDataToNetwork: Message send failed. Caught an exception");
                            publishProgress("2".getBytes());
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("AsyncTask", "SendDataToNetwork: Message send failed. Caught an exception");
                publishProgress("3".getBytes());
            }
        }
        Log.i("AsyncTask", "SendDataToNetwork: Message send failed. Socket closed");
        return messageSuccess;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values) {
        if (values.length > 0) {
            if (values[0].equals("1")){
                Log.i("AsyncTask", "onProgressUpdate: " + values[0].length + " bytes received.");
                c.toastmessage(context, getString(R.string.StatusSendAlarm), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            else if (values[0].equals("2")) {
                Log.i("AsyncTask", "onProgressUpdate2: " + values[0].length + " bytes received.");
                c.toastmessage(context, getString(R.string.StatusSendAlarmFail)+" 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            else if (values[0].equals("3")) {
                Log.i("AsyncTask", "onProgressUpdate3: " + values[0].length + " bytes received.");
                c.toastmessage(context, getString(R.string.StatusSendAlarmFail)+" 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            //textStatus.setText(new String(values[0]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Log.i("AsyncTask", "Cancelled.");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        if (socket) {
            Log.d("AsyncTask", getString(R.string.socket_success));
            if (nos != null) {
                if (messageSuccess) {
                    c.toastmessage(context, getString(R.string.alarm_success),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    mCheckBox.toggle();
                }
                else {
                    c.toastmessage(context, getString(R.string.alarm_fail),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    mCheckBox.toggle();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d("AsyncTask", getString(R.string.socket_fail));
        }


    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is the case?

EDIT: Here is he code, where the function "SendDataToNetwork" is called:

```
 private OnClickListener btnSendListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //toastmessage(context, "Sending Message to AsyncTask.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        EditText at = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alarmText);
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();
        String atext = at.getText().toString();

        if (atext.length() > 0) {
            String alarmtext = "<event>\n" +
                    "<address>" + EINHEIT + "</address>\n" +
                    "<timestamp>" + ts + "</timestamp>\n" +
                    "<message>" + atext + "</message>\n" +
                    "</event>";
            networktask.SendDataToNetwork(alarmtext);
        }
    }
};
```

And here is my onCreate function where the socket-connection is established.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(btnSendListener);
    mButton=(Button)findViewById( R.id.sendButton);
    mCheckBox= ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.checkBox_send);
    mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                mButton.setEnabled(true);
                mButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

            } else {
                mButton.setEnabled(false);
                mButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7c0000"));
            }

        }
    });
    context = getApplicationContext();
    networktask = new NetworkTask(); //New instance of NetworkTask
    networktask.execute();
}
```

Comment: Maybe the server closed the connection after receiving the first message.

Comment: 'public boolean SendDataToNetwork(final String cmd) { //You run this from the main thread.'. Indeed. So remove this function from your AsyncTask class and put it in your activity instead. Then show when and how you call it for the first and second time.

Comment: The function is called, when I press a button on the UI. I added the code above

Comment: Why aren't you commenting on my first comment?

Comment: Repeat: 'remove this function from your AsyncTask class and put it in your activity instead'.

Comment: sorry I'm new to stackoverflow and saw the comment-button under your comment. I can't comment on your comment.

I moved the function into the activity and am calling it in the OnClickListener via SendDataToNetwork(alarmtext). Still the same problem. First call works fine. Second one doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. I took your advice (connect, send, read in one task) and implemented it. Now the async task is called, when I press the button and it passed the string to the doInBackground function. There I create the socket connection, open OutputStream and send the message. Afterwards I close all connections.

I had to continue using "nos.close()" because sending a "\n" or "\n\n" did not work.

**Call of Async Task**

```
private OnClickListener btnSendListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText at = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alarmText);
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();
        String atext = at.getText().toString();

        if (atext.length() > 0) {
            String alarmtext = 
                    "<event>\n" +
                    "<address>" + EINHEIT + "</address>\n" +
                    "<timestamp>" + ts + "</timestamp>\n" +
                    "<message>" + atext + "</message>\n" +
                    "</event>";

            networktask = new NetworkTask(); //New instance of NetworkTask
            networktask.execute(alarmtext);
        }
        else {
            toastmessage(context, getString(R.string.noText), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
};
```

**Creation of socket**

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) { //This runs on a different thread
        messageSuccess = false;
        String alarmtext = params[0];
        try {
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "Background Task: Creating socket...");
            sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(SERVERHOST, SERVERPORT);
            nsocket = new Socket();
            nsocket.connect(sockaddr, 10000); //10 second connection timeout
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "Background Task: Socket created");
            nos = nsocket.getOutputStream();
            nos.write(alarmtext.getBytes());
            closeSocket();
            messageSuccess = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("AsyncTask", "Background Task: IOException");
            Log.i("AsyncTask", getString(R.string.socket_fail));
            messageSuccess = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("AsyncTask", "Background Task: Exception");
            Log.i("AsyncTask", getString(R.string.socket_fail));
            messageSuccess = false;
        }
        return messageSuccess;
    }
```

Thank you greenapps for helping

Comment: Some remarks: If you use messageSuccess, sockaddr and nsocket only in doInBackground (and i think you do), then declare them there. Further use e.getMessage() to see the right message. Log.e("AsyncTask", "Background Task: IOException: " + e.getMessage());

Answer (score 0):

```
    nos.close();
```

You yourself are closing the stream and hence the socket.

```
  nos = nsocket.getOutputStream();
```

You should do that only once. Not for every message.

Comment: Unfortunately the message it not send, when I don't close the Output Stream.

Comment: I had it the way you said at the beginning and after wondering why it's not sending the message I closed the Output Stream and it worked.

Comment: Ok. That happens often when the sender's `nos.write(cmd.getBytes());` does not match the receiver's `read()`. What is the receiver trying to read? Some bytes? A line? You did not send a line i think.

Comment: the text I am trying to send is
"<event>\n<address>" + EINHEIT + "</address>\n<timestamp>" + ts + "</timestamp>\n<message>" + atext + "</message>\n</event>"

The receiving end is a third-party-program that can receive this kind of string over a socket connection.

Comment: Try to send a \n at the end. Or two. So `nos.write((cmd + "\n").getBytes());`or `nos.write((cmd + "\n\n").getBytes());` You have to find out what the receiver expects as end of message. Ask the one who made the receiver. You did not answer my question what the receiver tried to read.

Comment: You should know what kind of protocol you have to implement. As you told us here you suggest you can keep a connection open for a long time while sending a command now and then. Are you sure that that is possible? It could be that for every command you send you have to open a new connection. If so then that is much easier as you can do the connect, send and read in one asynctask. And another question is why do you want to keep the connection open? Who told you that it was possible?